# Split string by specific substring

Tags: java, regex, string, split, substring

Say I have this string

```
[0] playerName19  [1] playerName17  [2] playerName18  [3] playerName15  [4]      playerName59  [5] playerName16  [6] playerName6  [7] playerName60
```

How do I split it into something like this, using Java:

```
[0] playerName19, [1] playerName17, [2] playerName18...
```

I tried using split() but the problem is that the playerName number extension is randomly generated and changes for each query.

Comment: you need to split the initial string or change the initial string to the second one separated by comma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split according to the space which exists before `[num]`.

```
string.split("\\s+(?=\\[\\d+\\])");
```